# Simulating background-size: cover with center position on HTML5 <video>

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to simulate the functionality of `background-size: cover` on `<video>` element. I have managed to do that with this following code:

```
<video id="videobackground" autoplay="true" loop="true">
    <source src="BackgroundFinal2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


#videobackground { 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; 
  z-index: -1000; 
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Problem is that I'd also like to simulate the functionality of `background-position: center center;` and I don't know how to do that. With the current code my video is cut off from the Left and the Top if required - however I want it to be cut from both sides.

Any ideas/solutions, please? Thanks!

Comment: A mere google search turned up http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video with a demo on top of it!

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem with centering the video. The code shown on the website is the same as mine. They only center the background image not the actual video.

Comment: can you elaborate the question a little bit? Are you trying to show text on top of the HTML5 video tag since you mentioned that your website is the same as Radu mentioned. I have updated the CSS here just to make sure that it starts from the top.  http://jsfiddle.net/seshakiran/ks9kad7f/

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: *I've only been experimenting with web development (or any sort of code/script) for about 9 months, so don't assume my solution is without fault. See footnote for known issues.*

I've been facing the same problem, and I think I understand exactly what you're looking for.

Basically, regardless of screen width/height, the video's horizontal and vertical edges should never enter the viewport, aspect ratio should be retained and the video should be centered vertically and horizontally.

Example for a video with a **1920x800** resolution:

*(CSS vendor prefixes are missing)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-vid-container">
    <video id="bg-vid" class="cover" poster="lib/img/bg-vid.poster.png" autoplay loop>
        <source src="lib/vid/bg-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg-vid-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

video.cover {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 240vh;
    height: auto;
}
```

---

The flex box model with `justify-content` and `align-items` set to center will keep the video vertically and horizontally centered and `overflow: hidden;` stops unwanted scrolling.

The `min-width` is set in this case to `240vh` (view height unit, where 1vh=1% of window height). This is calculated by scaling the aspect ratio to a height of 100 (I use Andrew Hedges' [Aspect Ratio Calculator](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/)).

1920x800 scales to **240**x100.

This will prevent the video's height from dropping below 100% but still allow it's width to be 100% if the browser window gets that wide, simply increasing its height at that point.

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/), the flex box model and the vh unit both have good support.

This wont work as desired (yet) on mobile seeing as on some devices, the keyboard sliding up resizes the window. I'm working on a jQuery/CSS media query solution to this. I'll update with results if they work as intended. iOS 7's support for vh is also a bit sketchy.